# Error de codificación en Python 3

Tags: html, python, html5, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código en python 3 el cual me esta causando problemas al momento de ejecutarlo, este codigo lo que hace o debería de hacer ya que no entiendo porque no funciona si ya lo eh implementado antes, es crear un html con nombre y datos variables los cuales toma de un archivo .json y los guarda dentro con un nombre especifico tomados del archivo json.

lo que esta dentro de plantilla = """ es lo que toma como plantilla y solo se reemplazan los datos variables marcados con {{}}

```
import json
from jinja2 import Template

datos = json.loads(open('DTHFOX.json').read())


plantilla = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>DTH ESTADO DE CUENTA</title>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-140129501-1"></script>
    <script>  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}  gtag('js', new Date());  gtag('require', 'displayfeatures');  gtag('config', 'UA-140129501-1');</script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icodish.png">
    <link href="styledthfox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
             <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
          <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>
          <em class="modedark">Modo Oscuro</em>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <article class="post"> 
            <table width="640" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style="font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0 auto;border:1px">       
                <tr><td><center><img border="0" id="imges"></center></td></tr>      
                <tr height="63"><td height="63" align="center" bgcolor="#d6212e">
                    <strong><font color="#fff" size="-1">HOLA, {{nombre}}</font><br /> 
                        <font color="#fff" size="5">ESTADO DE CUENTA DISH</font></strong></td></tr>     
                <tr><td><img src="img/bienvenida_estdo.png" alt="" width="640" ></td></tr>      
                <tr bgcolor="#fff"> <td>                
            <table align="center" bordercolor="#DAD6D9" bgcolor="#E4E1E3" width="500" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5>                  
                <tr><td align="right"><strong>NÚMERO DE SUSCRIPTOR: </strong></td><td><strong>{{c_cliente}}</strong></td></tr>                  
                <tr><tr><td align="right"><strong>SALDO AL CORTE: </strong></td><td>${{n_saldo}}</td></tr>                  
                <tr><td align="right"><strong>FECHA LÍMITE DE PAGO </strong></td><td>{{fecha_limite}}</td></tr>                 
                <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;font-size: 14px; vertical-align: middle;">Presente este código al pagar en su lugar favorito</td></tr>                    
                <tr><td colspan="2" align="center" style="background-color: #fff;"><img align="center" alt="Image" border="0" class="center autowidth" src="https://www.cerotec.net/gen_barcode.php?c={{n_tid}}&t=iso" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; clear: both; border: 0; height: auto; float: none; width: 100%; height: 70px;max-width: 300px; display: block;" title="Image" width="355"/></td></tr>                      
                <tr><td colspan="2" bgcolor="#F7F4F6" align="center"><font color="#000" size="2">*El monto a pagar que se indica en su mensualidad se modificará si realiza cambio de paquete o número de equipos. <br> *Evite cargos por pago tardío realizando su pago en la fecha indicada.</font> </td></tr>                
            </table>            
            <table align="center">              
                <tr><td><div style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:120%;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;"><div style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; color: #000; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; text-align: center; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 14x;">PARA SU COMODIDAD, RECUERDE QUE PUEDE<strong><br/>DOMICILIAR O REALIZAR SU PAGO CON TARJETA DE CRÉDITO O DÉBITO</strong> </span><br/><span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px;">PUEDE HACERLO DANDO CLIC AQUÍ</span></p></div></div><div align="center">
                        <a href="https://www.dish.com.mx/midish/login" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; background-color: #d6212e; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; width: auto; width: auto; border-top: 1px solid #d6212e; border-right: 1px solid #d6212e; border-bottom: 1px solid #d6212e; border-left: 1px solid #d6212e; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center; mso-border-alt: none; word-break: keep-all;" target="_blank">
                            <span style="padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;font-size:14px;display:inline-block;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 32px;"><strong><span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 28px;">MI DISH</span></strong>
                            <img src="img/mouseicon.png" width="17" height="17" style="vertical-align: bottom;"></span></span></a></div><div style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:120%;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
                                <div style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; color: #000; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                    <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px; text-align: center; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 14px;">O LLAMANDO AL TELÉFONO DE</span></p><p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px; text-align: center; margin: 0;">
                                        <img align="center" src="img/tel.png" width="20"><strong><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;"><a href="tel:015596283474" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #000;" title="tel:015596283474">ATENCIÓN A CLIENTES</a></span></strong></p></div></div></td></tr>           
            </table></td></tr>  
            <table width="640" class="table" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style="font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0 auto; border:1px">    
                <tr><td><a href="http://edosms.dish.com.mx/ok/freeback.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/FREE_FOX_min3.png" alt="" width="640" /a></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 28px; text-align: center; margin: 0;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14pt;"><strong class="post-meta">¡CONOZCA LOS SERVICIOS QUE TENEMOS PARA USTED!</strong></td></tr>       
                <tr><tr><td align="center">
                    <!--aqui inicia tripleplay-->
                    <img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2019-09-04-161114" src="img/tri3.png" border="0" width="640" height="500" orgWidth="640" orgHeight="500" usemap="#image-maps-2019-09-04-161114" alt="" />
                    <map name="image-maps-2019-09-04-161114" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2019-09-04-161114">
                        <area  alt="TPlay" title="Tryple Play" href="http://fpop.com.mx/" shape="rect" coords="0,0,640,400" style="outline:none;" target="_blank"     />
                        <area  alt="FP" title="Freedom Pop" href="https://www.dishcelular.com.mx/paquetes.html" shape="rect" coords="0,399,201,500" style="outline:none;" target="_blank"     />
                        <area  alt="ON" title="ON" href="https://oninternet.com.mx/" shape="rect" coords="199,399,401,500" style="outline:none;" target="_blank"     />
                        <area  alt="Dish" title="Dish" href="https://www.dish.com.mx/" shape="rect" coords="399,399,600,500" style="outline:none;" target="_blank"     />
                    </map>
                    <!--aqui termina triple play--></td></tr>
                    <tr><!--aqui inicia la imagen noggin--><td align="center">
                        <img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2019-08-28-192608" src="img/nt.png" border="0" width="640" height="204" orgWidth="640" orgHeight="204" usemap="#image-maps-2019-08-28-192608" alt="" />
                        <map name="image-maps-2019-08-28-192608" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2019-08-28-192608">
                            <area  alt="noggin" title="noggin" href="https://www.dishmovil.com.mx/mx/plataformas/noggin" shape="rect" coords="0,0,207,204" style="outline:none;" target="_blank"     />
                            <area  alt="Netbox" title="Netbox" href="https://www.dish.com.mx/NETBOX/index.html" shape="rect" coords="205,0,428,204" style="outline:none;" target="_blank"     />
                            <area  alt="Dish Móvil" title="Dish Móvil" href="https://www.dishmovil.com.mx/mx/home" shape="rect" coords="425,0,640,204" style="outline:none;" target="_blank"     />
                        </map></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="color:#555555;font-family:Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:120%;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; text-align: center; color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0;">
                        <strong>
                            <span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;" class="post-meta">ALGUNOS ESTABLECIMIENTOS QUE REPORTAN SU PAGO DE INMEDIATO SON:</span>
                        </strong>
                    </p></td></tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#EEECEE"><td><img src="img/TID.PNG" alt="" width="640" height="90" ></td></tr>     
                <tr><td bgcolor="#eeecee" align="center" height="30" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">               
                    <a href="https://www.dish.com.mx/soporte-y-servicio/lugares-de-pago-dish" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; background-color: #d6212e; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; width: auto; width: auto; border-top: 1px solid #d6212e; border-right: 1px solid #d6212e; border-bottom: 1px solid #d6212e; border-left: 1px solid #d6212e; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center; mso-border-alt: none; word-break: keep-all;" target="_blank">
                        <span style="padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;font-size:14px;display:inline-block;">
                            <span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 32px;">
                                <strong>
                                    <span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 28px;">CONSULTA AQUÍ TODOS LOS LUGARES DONDE PUEDES PAGAR</span>
                                </strong>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </a><div style="color:#555555;font-family:Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:120%;padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;"><div style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; color: #555555; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;"><p style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px; text-align: center; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 10px;">SI NO CUENTA CON SU TARJETA DISH (TID) O LA EXTRAVIO ENVÍE UN CORREO CON SU NÚMERO DE CLIENTE A <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 13px;"><strong><a href="mailto:soportetid@dish.com.mx?subject=Solicito tarjeta DISH&amp;body=Hola Dish favor de enviar mi tarjeta DISH, mi nÚmero de cliente es:" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #555555;" title="soportetid@dish.com.mx">soportetid@dish.com.mx</a></strong></span></span><br/><span style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 12px;">O COMUNÍQUESE A, <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 13px;"><strong><a href="tel:015596283474" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #555555;" title="tel:015596283474">ATENCIÓN A CLIENTES </a> </strong></span>Y SOLICÍTELA.</span></p><p style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; margin: 0;"> </p></div></div></td></tr>      
                <tr><td><img src="img/bienvenida_05_2.png" alt="" width="640" ></td></tr>   
                <tr><td style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 13px; text-align: center; margin: 0;">
                    <span style="font-size: 11px;" class="post-meta">*Aplica únicamente para tu servicio de televisión.</span></td></tr>    
                <tr><td align="center"><a href="tel:015596283474"><img align="center" src="img/pidelo_ya.png" alt="" width="400" ></a></td></tr>            
                <tr style="background-color:#4c4c4c;width:100% !important;"><div style="border-top:0px solid transparent; border-left:0px solid transparent; border-bottom:0px solid transparent; border-right:0px solid transparent; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;"> <td style="padding:.5em 0;color:#fff;" align="center">            
                    <a href="https://www.dish.com.mx/legal" rel="noopener" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;font-size:10px;font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;" target="_blank">AVISO DE PRIVACIDAD</a> &#8226;                
                    <a href="https://www.dish.com.mx/terminos-de-uso" rel="noopener" style="text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;font-size:10px;font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;" target="_blank">TÉRMINOS Y CONDICIONES</a></td></tr> 
            </table> 
        <article>   
    </section>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');
        const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
        if (currentTheme) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
        if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
        toggleSwitch.checked = true;
                }
            }

        function switchTheme(e) {
         if (e.target.checked) {
         document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
         localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
          }
         else {        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
         localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
               }    
        }
        toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
"""
plantilla.encode('utf8')

for persona in datos:
  result = Template(plantilla).render(**persona)
  with open(persona["Tipo_EST"], "w",) as f:
     f.write(result)
```

a lo cual yo no le encuentro falla, de codificación o algo por el estilo, resulta que al ejecutar el comando en la consola cmd de windows me marca el siguiente error

```
C:\Users\eduardo.lopeza\Downloads\PROGRAMACION\PYTHON>python DTHFOX.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DTHFOX.py", line 135, in <module>
    f.write(result)
  File "C:\Users\eduardo.lopeza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\en
codings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8d' in position 39
62: character maps to <undefined>
```

eso es lo que me sale en la consola de comando, ya intenten tratar de codificar de varios modos pero ese error me sigue apareciendo en todos los modos que intento

estoy usando import json y jinj2 en python, me podrían ayudar a saber a que se debe ese error.

Comment: Podrías sacarme la duda e intentar hacer esto?   `plantilla = plantilla.encode('utf8')`

Comment: hola gracias por responder, ya lo intente pero no me funciona

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters quizás te sea de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a ver si esto te funciona:

```
plantilla = plantilla.encode('latin-1')
```

Yo me hago un lío con la codificación de caracteres, y esto me ha salvado la vida mas de una vez.

También puedes probar:

```
plantilla = plantilla.encode('850')
```

En ocasiones el problema es la propia codificación de tu script, asegúrate de que estás trabajando con un editor de texto que guarda tus archivos codificados en *utf-8*. Existen conversores online como [este](https://subtitletools.com/convert-text-files-to-utf8-online).

¡Suerte!

Comment: gracias voy a probar y comento que me funciona